# Calculated Column colour coded result

Tags: calculated-column

I have created a list on our new company sharepoint to track monthly sales orders, a kind of very basic sales pipeline if you will.

In our list we have "Sales Price" and "Cost Price" columns and from that, i am using two calculated columns to show "Profit" and "Margin" (as a %).

What i am looking to do, is colour code the "Margin" column as per the example below.

[image: Example]

The code i am using to calculate the margin column is:

```
=Profit/[Sales Price]
```

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the use of those calculated columns to provide the color coding you need. With the help of CEWP, you can use the calculated formula to provide additional formatting and the formula will determine which color the value will be.

You need the a script to load on a CEWP and make changes to the calculated column.

Check out this link to follow the steps to it:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/apply-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for that, i had read that earlier, but struggled to make that work with my existing calculation code. Would you be able to advise on the best way to formulate this as when i tried i kept getting syntax errors :(

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at following article

- [Using calculated columns to add color coding to your SharePoint lists](http://sarahlhaase.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/)

There are a variety of ways to add color coding to your SharePoint lists and document libraries, from embedding custom code on your page to creating data view web parts with conditional formatting in SharePoint Designer. The trick is determining which method works best in your situation.

Solution works for 2007 & 2010 versions.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an article on the various ways of achieving this on our company blog. These are (in summary):

**Client based**

- *JavaScript*: Put some JavaScript code into a Content Editor Web Part
- *Designer*: Use SharePoint Designer to set up Conditional Formatting

**Custom Field Type**

- *Code it yourself*: Make your own custom field type from scratch
- *Buy*: Purchase a pre-made solution (naturally, I recommend our own product 'SharePoint Highlighter')

More information, links, and persuasive sales talk can be found in the article: [How to do list highlighting in SharePoint](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-to-do-list-highlighting-in-sharepoint/)